# Navigations with dropdowns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm really stuck on this one and could really use help. So I have this code:

```
<nav>
      <a class="opcion-1" title="Opcion 1" href="#">Quiénes somos</a>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a class="opcion-2" title="Opcion 2" href="#">Nuestro trabajo</a>
      <a class="opcion-3" title="Opcion 3" href="#">UNAC news</a>
      <a class="opcion-4" title="Opcion 4" href="#">Cómo donar</a>
      <a class="lupa" title="Opcion 5" href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Gotham book;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  border-right: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

nav > .lupa {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/kXm05cw.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
nav a.opcion-1:hover {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/JnbTq5a.png);
}

nav > a:hover {
  background-color: #FFB53A;
  color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

What I need is for `Link1` and the others to drop down when the parent `a` is selected. These will then drop down and reveal text inside. I need to be able to customize them as well. You can see what I need below.

[image]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is already built in to the JQuery library.
Its called Accordion.

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Here is an example of the accordion.

```
<div id="accordion">
<a href="#one" class="first">Recent Posts</a>
<div id="one">
    this is some info.
</div>

<a href="#two">Popular Posts</a>
<div id="two">
    this is some more info.
</div>

<a href="#three">Archived Posts</a>
<div id="three">
    this is even more info.
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edsilv/cgn4s8y7/

Comment: You would then put that accordion in a jquery tab plugin or another tab plugin maybe boostrap.
http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/

Comment: I can't seem to be able to import the code. The CSS and text is alright, but the tabs don't change.

Comment: Can you post a link

Comment: If the tabs are not changing you are having a javascript error I would check your inspector and console for js errors if it still dont work debug through the javascript under the inspector under the sources tab. if you can give me some details there or a screen shot I can help you ascertain whats going on.